# Why was this question "How to improve my listening skill?" closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Why was this question "How to improve my listening skill?" closed?
[How to improve my listening skill?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26625/how-to-improve-my-listening-skill)

while this question is not closed.
[How can I speed up my speech?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48351/how-can-i-speed-up-my-speech)

It seems to me that the both questions ask questions in almost equal generality.

Comment: Because the closed question was asked six months ago, and the open question was asked one hour ago. Give the system time to work. Also, the newer question does end with a more specific question, so perhaps many in the community will decide to leave that newer question open.